# python program to find prime number n by seeing if they can divide evenly into prime numbers less that the squareroot of n

Tags: python

How do I make this return the right results for primes less than 10 ?

```
from math import *

def isPrime(n):

i = [c for c in range(int(sqrt(n)),0,-1) if c % 2 != 0 and c > 1 ]

for x in i: 
    if n % x == 0:
        return print('%s is not prime' % (n))
return print('%s is prime number' %(n))


def main():

loopCnt = 'y'
while loopCnt != 'n':
    n = int(input('Enter a integer greater than 2: '))
    isPrime(n)


    loopCnt = input('Enter any key to try again or enter n to exit').strip().lower()


main()
```

It is not giving the desired output

Comment: What exactly is the problem? And please format your code correctly: highlight it in the editor then click the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you exit the `for` loop in the first iteration *always*. You should only exit when you find it has a divisor, but otherwise you should keep looping. When you exit the loop without finding a divisor then is the time to return that fact.

So change:

```
for x in i: 
    if n % x == 0:
        return print('%s is not prime' % (n))
    else:
        return print('%s is prime number' %(n))
```

to:

```
for x in i: 
    if n % x == 0:
        return print('%s is not prime' % (n))
return print('%s is prime number' %(n))
```

Secondly, your `i` array includes the number 1, and since all numbers are dividable by 1 that does not make sense. So the range should stop before 1 instead of 0. Also, you should include 2 as a divider.

So change:

```
i = [c for c in range(int(math.sqrt(n)),0,-1) if c % 2 != 0]
```

By:

```
i = [c for c in range(int(math.sqrt(n)),1,-1) if c % 2 != 0] + [2]
```

See it in [repl.it](https://repl.it/DxN2/1)

Comment: when I do this a plug 3 as the test number it doesn't display anything

Comment: I was just adding a second issue that needed correction when you made your comment. I also added a link to repl.it to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = [c for c in range(int(sqrt(n)),0,-1) if c % 2 != 0]
```

This code is skipping all even divisors. This is correct for *most* divisors, but it incorrectly skips 2, so it will misclassify even numbers!

You need to make an exception for 2, either in the filter or by adding a special case to check whether `n` is an even number greater than 2.

(As an aside, checking divisors in reverse order will slow you down. Small divisors are more common in randomly chosen composite numbers than large ones.)

Comment: how can  I fix this i'm pretty new to python, appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Duskwolf, the line where you check for primes is wrong. A replacement function could simply be

```
import numpy as np

def isPrime(n):
    len = int(sqrt(n))
    divisors = np.zeros(len, dtype=np.bool)
    for i in range(1,len):
        if(n%(i+1)==0):
            divisors[i]=True
    prime = not divisors.any()
    if(prime):
        return print('%s is prime' % (n))
    return print('%s is not a prime number' %(n))
```